# can't start Apache

Tags: apache2, bluetooth

given: win11. wsl w/Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS.
no nginx servers installed, no services listening on ports 80.
installed systemd
installed apache2

errors:

1. systemctl status apache2.service
   ● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2023-04-23 11:09:43 CDT; 14s ago
   Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
   Process: 5885 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   CPU: 52ms
2. journalctl -xe
   only error relates to
   -- Startup of the manager took 750592 microseconds.
   Apr 22 22:05:54 Blinpad pulseaudio[1243]: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
   Apr 22 22:26:35 Blinpad systemd[1232]: mnt-wsl-user-121.mount: Succeeded.
   -- Subject: Unit succeeded
   -- Defined-By: systemd
3. tried to remove org.bluez with
   sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove pulseaudio-module-bluetooth

but the the error still there.

4. tried to uninstall/reinstall apache2 several times. no change.
5. the only change before trying to install Apache was
   creating  /etc/wsl.conf file and adding following line:
   [boot]
   systemd=true

Can't figure out why apache2 having starting issue. Any help would be appreciated. This is my first post on SE.

Comment: There should be some actionable errors recorded in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` that point to the issue. This is where Apache will record any serious issues.

Comment: nope. there are no errors. and files are empty.                                                               
-rw-r-----  1 root adm       0 Apr 22 22:24 access.log
-rw-r-----  1 root adm       0 Apr 22 22:24 error.log
-rw-r-----  1 root adm       0 Apr 22 22:24 other_vhosts_access.log